# Ruby SE API: A Ruby wrapper for the Stack Exchange API

Tags: library, api, ruby

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

An excerpt from the README:

> First, initialize your client. You can omit the API key, but it's
>   strongly recommended that you use one because it increases your
>   request limit drastically. Also, any parameters that you pass on
>   initialization will be passed with any request (but can be overridden
>   later). It is recommended that you set the `site` this way.
>
> ```
> require 'se/api'
>
> cli = SE::API::Client.new(ENV['APIKey'], site: 'stackoverflow')
> ```
>
> Now that you've initialized the client, you can use the instance
>   methods provided:
>
> > Note: All the routes below pass `**params` directly to the API.
>
> - `post(id, **params)`: Gets a post based on the ID passed.
> - `posts(*ids, **params)`: Get posts based on either a semicolon delimited string of ids or an array of ids.
> - `question(id, **params)`: Gets a question based on the ID passed.
> - `questions(*ids, **params)`: Gets questions based on either a semicolon delimited string of ids or an array of ids.
> - `answer(id, **params)`: Gets an answer based on the ID passed.
> - `answers(*ids, **params)`: Gets answers based on either a semicolon delimited string of ids or an array of ids.
> - `user(id, **params)`: Gets a user based on the ID passed.
> - `users(*ids, **params)`: Gets users based on either a semicolon delimited string of ids or an array of ids.

### About

I needed a gem for the Stack Exchange API for some chatbots I was working on, so I wrote this.

#### License

This project is released under the MIT License. Any contributions are welcome via pull requests. Feature requests can be made via issues or in chat.

#### Download

Although the library is [published on rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/se-api), the version there will frequently be outdated. To keep up to date, please [install from GitHub](https://github.com/thesecretmaster/se-api). The master branch should never be broken, so `bundle update` regularly. This is easy if you're using the bundler gem, you can just add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'se-api', git: 'https://github.com/thesecretmaster/se-api`, branch: 'master'
```

#### Platform

This library should work anywhere Ruby will run. That means definitely macOS/Linux, and possibly Windows.

### Contact

If you are getting started, I know that documentation is poor, so please ping me in chat. I can be found in either of the two testing rooms for this library, [Under the Bed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63561/under-the-bed) and [The Closet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63296/the-closet). Ping me whenever, and I should respond within 48 hours.

In addition, if you have any feature requests, ping me in chat. I would be more than happy to try to add functions you need or to help you better use the Ruby SE API.

### Dependencies

- MRI Ruby 2.5.0